# Changing Windows.Ribbon background color

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I am working with the `System.Windows.Ribbon` in my project. I am also using some other libraries like `AvalonDocking`,... What I want to do is create my own themes inside the application so that the user can select the prefered theme.

The problem is that I don't get the `RibbonTab` to change to the correct colors. When I change the ribbon background color the `RibbonTab` color changes also. But I want to change it seperatly

**Does anybody have any experience with changing the layout of the System.Windows.Ribbon?**

This is what I tried before:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="Black"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RibbonTab}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="88" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:DockingManager}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

[image: Result of theme]

As you can see, the `RibbonTab` is not black like specified inside the `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: Have a read of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22fa73e4-b1db-43ae-83fc-4f50c26f7a0c/placing-a-background-to-a-tab-on-a-ribbon-control?forum=wpf#6d716cea-1624-4b20-b444-f5a4c9445bc8

Comment: That is actually what I need :) Thx