# Different background color for selected RibbonTab

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, ribbon

I have a WPF Window with a `Ribbon` with a dark background color (`SolidColorBrush`)

I have set the font color of the tabs to white, but that's not readable in the selected tab. So I would like to have a black background in the selected tab (or a black font color would also work).
My app.xaml contains this code to style it:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="SelectedRibbonTab" TargetType="RibbonTab">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="RibbonTab">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedRibbonTab}"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It is clearly not working, any solutions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single style to change the header text color (`Foreground`) using [`IsRibbonTabSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontabheader.isribbontabselected?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonTabHeader.IsRibbonTabSelected);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0).

```
<Style TargetType="RibbonTabHeader">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsRibbonTabSelected" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Changing the background of a ribbon tab is not recommended, as it is not that trivial. The ribbon and ribbon tab backgrounds can be customized by setting the `Background` property of the `Ribbon` itself. This will in turn adapt the background color of **all** tabs in **all states**. These backgrounds use gradients and are defined in the respective control templates. Again, it is not easy to even get these control templates, see:

- [How to customize the WPF Ribbon 4.5 (styles, templates, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17488075/6181599)

If you want to try it nevertheless, here is a related post that links an MSDN forum  answer that offers a possible style and control template that might be adapted. However, I recommend to simply use the style above.

- [Changing Windows.Ribbon background color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38390835/6181599)
- [Placing a Background to a Tab on a Ribbon Control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22fa73e4-b1db-43ae-83fc-4f50c26f7a0c/placing-a-background-to-a-tab-on-a-ribbon-control?forum=wpf#6d716cea-1624-4b20-b444-f5a4c9445bc8)

An alternative is to use the Fluent.Ribbon instead, which offers more support for customization.

- [Fluent.Ribbon GitHub](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon)
- [Fluent.Ribbon NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fluent.Ribbon)
- [Fluent.Ribbon Docs on Creating Custom Themes](https://fluentribbon.github.io/documentation/styles_since_8#custom)